# HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET setting in doxygen config file

Tags: doxygen

I was using doxygen 1.7.6.1 (which seems to be the latest version available in a deb package available to Ubuntu), and it didn't seem to support the configuration file setting HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET along with a couple of others I wanted to use.

So I installed a new version from the binary distribution (1.8.3.1). Here's what I did for a quick test:

1. edited my Doxyfile to add the line HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = custom.css
2. put the custom.css file in the same directory as the Doxyfile
3. ran doxygen and generated the output

In the resulting output, there is no reference to the custom.css file, nor is there a copy of it in the output directory.

So... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a custom header via HTML_HEADER maybe?

Comment: I did get it to work, though, by specifying the full path to my custom file. I thought for sure doxygen would look for it by default in the same directory as the Doxyfile lives, but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: It should also have worked with a relative path from where doxygen is run.